# percentage symbol in strings.xml

Tags: android, xml, string, format

I'm trying to format a string from string.xml to reuse it with several Values. I'm running into some problems as the String should also contain the percentage-symbol which is used by the formatter. I already tried to replace the % symbol by its Unicode presentation but that doesn't seem to work:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="teststring">The new value is %1$s%</string>
    <string name="teststring2">The new value is %1$s\u0025</string>
    <string name="teststring3">The new value is %1$s</string>
</resources>
```

Java Code:

```
String value = "25";
String formattedString = context.getResources().getString(R.string.teststring), value);
```

In this example, `teststring` and `teststring2` will produce an error, while `teststring3` works fine. What's the correct way to put that % symbol in the xml-string to get "The new value is 25%" as formatted String?

Stacktrace:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.util.UnknownFormatConversionException: Conversion: 
    at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifierParser.unknownFormatConversionException(Formatter.java:2304)
    at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifierParser.advance(Formatter.java:2298)
    at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifierParser.parseConversionType(Formatter.java:2377)
    at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifierParser.parseArgumentIndexAndFlags(Formatter.java:2348)
    at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifierParser.parseFormatToken(Formatter.java:2281)
    at java.util.Formatter.doFormat(Formatter.java:1069)
    at java.util.Formatter.format(Formatter.java:1040)
    at java.util.Formatter.format(Formatter.java:1009)
    at java.lang.String.format(String.java:1988)
    at android.content.res.Resources.getString(Resources.java:343)
    at (... and so on)
```

The correct answer is

```
<string name="teststring">The new value if %1$s%%</string>
```

formatted="false" must not be set.

Comment: i edited answer try it

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Use

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="teststring">The new value is %1$s%%</string>

</resources>
```

In java

```
String value = "25";
String formattedString =
    String.format(getResources().getString(R.string.teststring), value);
Log.i("",formattedString);
```

Comment: %% works, but there is should be posibility of having unicode characters to be added in strings.xml file

Comment: crashing for me when running 4.4.2

Answer (score 9):

Can you try `\%%` instead of % ??

Like,

```
<string name="teststring">The new value is \%%</string>
```

Or

```
<string formatted="false" name="teststring" >The new value is %</string>
```

Answer (score 9):

Try this

```
<string  name="teststring"> The new value is %1$s %% </string>
```

Answer (score 2):

Check this one,

```
<string name="teststring">The new value is %1$s %%</string>

String value = "25";
String formattedString = this.getResources().getString(R.string.teststring, mPageNumber);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
String value = "25";

String formattedString = "The new value is " + value + (char) 0x0025;
```

If now Log.d(TAG, formattedString); it will logs

```
The new value is 25%
```

Answer (score 0):

Use like this:

```
String str = context.getResources().getString(R.string.teststring);
String formattedString = String.format(str, value);
```

Comment: shoulnt this be the same as String str = context.getResources().getString(R.string.teststring, value); ?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <resources>
        <string name="offerString">The new value is %1$s%% %2$s</string>
    </resources>

String offerOnHdfc = "25";
String formattedString = String.format(getResources().getString(R.string.offerString), offerOnHdfc);
Log.i("",formattedString);
```