# Trying to write a the symbol '%' in strings.xml

Tags: android, string-formatting

I've tried all the [possible variations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16834196/percentage-symbol-in-strings-xml) I've found here on StackOverflow for writing a percent (%) symbol and I my app keeps crashing.

Here is what I want the text to look like:

50.0%
Complete.

Here is the string I am escaping in my strings.xml file:

```
<string name="work_package_percent_complete">%.1f%%\nComplete</string>
```

The error I am getting from the compiler is:

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>      Process: com.bechtel.pf.mock, PID: 8252
>      java.util.UnknownFormatConversionException: Conversion = '
>      '

Here's where I am calling String.format:

```
@JvmStatic
fun formatPercentageText(context: Context, percentage: Float): String {
    return String.format(
        context.resources.getString(
            R.string.work_package_percent_complete,
            percentage
            )
        )

}
```

It seems like it's not getting escaped properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that there was no reason to do String.format() when just retrieving the string would automatically handle the formatting for me.

So it just becomes:

```
@JvmStatic
fun formatPercentageText(context: Context, percentage: Float): String {
    return context.resources.getString(
            R.string.work_package_percent_complete,
            percentage
            )
}
```